# Synchronize threads to the WEBrick server start

Tags: ruby, multithreading, mocking, webrick

I am trying to start a small WEBrick server to mock a real API, to test a Ruby http client I am developing. I am using a modified solution of the one based in [this](http://dynamicorange.com/2009/02/18/ruby-mock-web-server/#comment-4546) blog comment.

It works fine, but the problem is that each time the server starts, the parent thread has to wait an arbitrary amount of time for the server to load. And after adding several tests it gets really slow.

So my question is: **is there a way to synchronize the parent thread to continue right after the server thread has finished starting WEBRick?**

I tried looking at the WEBrick reference, searched the web and even had a look in the WEBrick code, but I got nothing I could use without some really nasty monkey patching.

I'm open to other approaches to the problem, but I would like to keep it as dependency-free to gems and libraries as possible. Also, the solutions **must** run in **Ruby 1.9.2**, on **Linux**.

Thanks in advance for the answers!

```
require "rack"
class ApiMockServer
  def initialize(port = 4000, pause = 1)
    @block = nil
    @parent_thread = Thread.current
    @thread = Thread.new do
      Rack::Handler::WEBrick.run(self, :Port => port, :Host => "127.0.0.1")
    end

    sleep pause # give the server time to fire up… YUK!
  end

  def stop
    Thread.kill(@thread)
  end

  def attach(&block)
    @block = block
  end

  def detach()
    @block = nil
  end

  def call(env)
    begin
      unless @block
        raise "Specify a handler for the request using attach(block). The " +
          "block should return a valid rack response and can test expectations"
      end
      @block.call(env)
    rescue Exception => e
      @parent_thread.raise e
      [ 500, { 'Content-Type' => 'text/plain', 'Content-Length' => '13' }, [ 'Bad test code' ]]
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're Rack testing something why not use Rack::Test which does just this?

Comment: I didn't used it mostly because I didn't knew about it... :-)
Also, it would be better if the http client tests didn't have any external dependencies.
Still, I'll have a look at it... From what I've seen it completely removes the WEBrick server, and just returns the prepared response I made... Which is very interesting...
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: yes, it mocks all your requests. Sorry for the response then, assumed everybody knows Rack::Test who's using Rack or Rails :)